# SignalR client exists only inside OnConnectedAsync method

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr

I have `BaseHub` class that is inheriting `Hub` class. I overrode OnConnected and OnDisconnected methods, and they are working properly, when client and server are connected, `ConnectionId` is saved inside group.

```
public class BaseHub : Hub
{
    private readonly string _defaultGroupName = "HubUsers";

    public async Task BroadcastMessage(string methodName, params object[] parameters)
    {
        await Clients.All.SendAsync(methodName, parameters);
    }

    public async Task AddUserToGroup(string groupName)
    {
        await Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, groupName);
    }

    public async Task RemoveUserFromGroup(string groupName)
    {
        await Groups.RemoveFromGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, groupName);
    }

    public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
    {
        await AddUserToGroup(_defaultGroupName);
        await base.OnConnectedAsync();
    }

    public override async Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception exception)
    {
        await RemoveUserFromGroup(_defaultGroupName);
        await base.OnDisconnectedAsync(exception);
    }
}
```

When I call `BroadcastMessage`, my `Clients` is always null, thus I get exception.
When I tried to call `await Clients.All.SendAsync(methodName, parameters);` directly inside OnConnected, `Clients` object was valid and my client side method was invoked.
I even tried using `protected IHubContext<BaseHub> _context;`, then I have `_context` object, but 0 users insite Clients/ Groups.

`BaseHub` is parent class of `VotingHub` where I am calling `BroadcastMessage`

```
public async Task ShareResult(Guid result)
    {
        await BroadcastMessage(_receiveResult, new[] { result });
    }
```

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47465481/signalr-hubs-clients-are-null-when-firing-event but I've done something like this in my solution `GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<BaseHub>()`?

Comment: What exactly is null? There is no `Client`? Do you mean `Clients`? Where does the hub come from, where is it constructed? What calls `ShareResult`? Where does `_receiveResult` come from?

Comment: @AlanCheung I tried with context, then I don't have connections at clients at all, but I am not sure if I registered it as transient, I will check

Comment: @poke Yes `Clients`, my bad, Hub is registered in startup, hub is connected with FE, that part is okay, I tested it.  `ShareResult` is called inside service, and `_receiveResult` is string constant that I am using as method name

Comment: _“ShareResult is called inside service”_ – So you call this method from outside of a hub method? That won’t work. Hubs are only for _receiving_ from clients. If you want to call clients from elsewhere (e.g. MVC actions), [you will need a `IHubContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hubcontext?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

Comment: @poke true, I found that on documentation, but I didn't know that hubs are only for receiving from client, so basically I need to create helper that will allow me to send to client using IHubClient ?

Comment: If you want to send something to clients (outside of the context of a hub action), you will need to inject a hub context via DI.

Comment: @poke but can I send to clients inside Hub? I am confused now because u stated `Hubs are only for receiving from clients.`, so to be clear, can I use hub to sent to clients or only to receive from them?

Comment: Hubs are like controllers in that they the entry point when receiving messages (like actions receive HTTP requests). If you are within the hub flow, you *can* send messages to your clients. If you are not within the hub flow however, e.g. when you received a HTTP request inside a controller action, then you will need a hub context to send messages out.